# Doctrine_RawSql custom Select

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I having problems to generate a doctrine_rawsql with a custom select.

This is my rawsql

```
$distance = glength(linestringfromwkb(linestring(asbinary(GeomFromText('POINT( FLOAT('30') FLOAT('-3')),asbinary({l.point})))) as distance

$q->select($distance)
                ->from('place p INNER JOIN location l ON p.location_id = l.id')
                ->addComponent('p', 'Place p')
                ->addComponent('l', 'p.Location l')
```

if I do a `$q->getSql()` the distance doesn't appears in the generated sql.

Any ideas? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2287368/aggregate-values-in-doctrine-rawsql-queries is also trying the same, but hasn't been answered. Did you have any success?

Comment: I modified the Doctrine code inorder to allow this. Doctrine only supports SQL standard. This Geom functions/Data arent supported.

Comment: How exactly didn't you modify Doctrine to allow this? I'm also having this problem and am unsure or how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be solved now using Doctrine_Expression

```
$user = new User(); 
$user->username = 'jwage'; 
$user->updated_at = new Doctrine_Expression('NOW()'); 
$user->save();
```