# Aggregate values in Doctrine_RawSql queries

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-1.2

Is it possible to use aggregate values in Doctrine_RawSql query? Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$q->select('{q.*}, AVG(a.value) AS avg');
$q->from('-- complex from clause');
$q->addComponent('q', 'Question');
```

However, SQL created by Doctrine leaves only columns from table `question` and omits aggregate value `avg`.

Comment: First try to add component for alias "a" (you have "a.value" in query).

Comment: I'm trying to accomplish the same, but I'm also having difficulties. Have you fixed it since?

Answer (score 6):

I've never used Doctrine_RawSql before, but I have done raw SQL queries through Doctrine using either of these two methods:

```
Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc("YOUR SQL QUERY HERE");
```

and

```
$doctrine = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->getDbh();
$result = $doctrine->query('YOUR SQL QUERY HERE');
```

It seems like these two methods would leave your original SQL intact.

I should note that I'm using Doctrine 1.2 within the context of Symfony 1.4 applications, but AFAIK, this would work for you regardless of what other frameworks you may be using.

Comment: I opted to use the first solution, as I had to link two tables via a value which may exist in one and not in the other, using a LOJ. But I also had a where clause and wasn't sure how to bind the value, you can actually pass an array of placeholders => values as the 2nd argument to `fetchAssoc`, something like `fetchAssoc('SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = :userId'), array('userId' => $user->getId());`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [doctrine cookbook section on aggregates](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/2.0/docs/cookbook/aggregate-fields/en#aggregate-fields)? They use `createQuery` method on the entity manager rather than `RawSql` objects.

I'm no expert with doctrine, but this could be a good place to start!

Comment: My question applies to Doctrine 1.x. Doctrine 2.0 is completely different story.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the aggregate field in the SQL and then fetch it using curly brackets. 
I'm using SQL subquery.

```
$q = new Doctrine_RawSql();
$q->select('{s.*}, {s.avg} AS avg');
$q->from('(SELECT q.*, AVG(value) AS avg FROM Question AS q) AS s');
$q->addComponent('s', 'Question');
```

It works for me.